# Segfault after adding #pragma loop

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I faced a little trouble. I'm not sure if I can understand it.
So, I have some code. And I'm trying to add #pragma loop(hint_parallel(8)) statement for a few loops in the code. 
When I compile that using necessary compilation options which are actually like this:

> gcc -w -funroll-loops -O2 -fno-inline -fipa-pta -msse2
>   -funsafe-math-optimizations  -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=1 -fopt-info-optimized=logs/optOpt.txt -shared -fPIC singleThread.cpp

I get segmentation fault.

> fish: './a.out' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

The point is that I have no idea why it is. I suspected that it could be a problem with a constant that is used in these loops. But I don't think that this is related. if I just compile this code using -O0 optimisation it works fine (because complier doesn't vectorise something I guess).

Could you please take a look on the code below and suggest me in which direction I should check.
Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <cstdio>
#include <set>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

const int STRING_HASH_SIZE = 32;

int convert(vector<string> &inputVector, const char **outputArray);

void printCollisions(const char **charArray, int size);

void printArray(const char **arrayToPrint, int size);

int getHashCode(const char *characters, unsigned long size);

string getRandomString();

void writeFileIfNeeded(vector<string> &vector, bool needToWrite);

vector<string> generateStringsVector(int size, bool isNeedToWriteFile);

/**
 * main method is present to test these native code.
 * to perform some external operation we should use another method.
 * @return
 */
int main() {

    /**
     * The constant represents number of strings that will be generated
     * in the string vector generation.
    */
    const int STRING_NUMBERS = 100000;

    vector<string> inputVector = generateStringsVector(STRING_NUMBERS, false);

#pragma pack 8
    const char *charArray[inputVector.size()];

    int hashResult = convert(inputVector, charArray);

    if (hashResult != 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    printCollisions(charArray, STRING_NUMBERS);
}

/**
 * Converts an input vector to char array.
 * Getting a hash of
 * Returns 0 if conversion from vector to array has been successfully performed.
 * @param  inputVector [ input array reference ]
 * @param outputArray [ a char array that would contain char sequences from vector ]
 * @return           [ hash sum (int)]
 */
int convert(vector<string> &inputVector, const char **outputArray) {
    int hashSum = 0;
#pragma loop(hint_parallel(8))
    for (int i = 0; i < inputVector.size(); i++) {
        outputArray[i] = inputVector[i].c_str();
    }

#pragma loop(hint_parallel(8))
    for (auto &i : inputVector) {
        hashSum += getHashCode(i.c_str(), i.length());
    }

    int stringHashSize = STRING_HASH_SIZE;
#pragma loop(hint_parallel(8))
    for (int i = 0; i < inputVector.size(); i++) {
        hashSum -= getHashCode(outputArray[i], stringHashSize);
    }

    if (hashSum != 0) {
        cout << "\nConversion isn't succeeded, hash = " << hashSum << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "\nConversion succeeded" << endl;
    }
    return hashSum;
}

/**
 * Prints count and percentage of collisions in array hash codes
 * @param charArray
 * @param size
 */
void printCollisions(const char **charArray, int size) {
    set<int> setOfHashes;
    int stringHashSize = STRING_HASH_SIZE;
#pragma loop(hint_parallel(8))
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        setOfHashes.insert(getHashCode(charArray[i], stringHashSize));
    }
    unsigned long collisions = size - setOfHashes.size();
    cout << collisions << "/" << size << " " << 100.0 * collisions / size << "% of collisions";
}

/**
 * Prints input char array
 * @param arrayToPrint
 */
void printArray(const char **arrayToPrint, int size) {
    cout << "\nPrinted array size = " << size << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << arrayToPrint[i] << ":" << getHashCode(arrayToPrint[i], STRING_HASH_SIZE) << endl;
    }
}

/**
 *
 * @param characters
 * @return
 */
int getHashCode(const char *characters, unsigned long size) {
    int hash = 0;
#pragma loop(hint_parallel(8))
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        hash = (31 + hash) * (characters[i]);
    }
    return hash;
}

/**
 * Get a random String from alphabetical char sequence.
 * @return a randomized string according to an alphabet.
 */
string getRandomString() {
    string str("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 generator(rd());
    shuffle(str.begin(), str.end(), generator);
    return str.substr(0, STRING_HASH_SIZE);
}

/**
 * Generates a vector with random strings
 * @param size - an int value that will be used as size of a generated vector
 * @return reference to generated vector.
 */
vector<string> generateStringsVector(int size, bool isNeedToWriteFile) {
    vector<string> charArray;
#pragma loop(hint_parallel(8))
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        string str = getRandomString();
        charArray.push_back(str);
    }
    writeFileIfNeeded(charArray, isNeedToWriteFile);
    return charArray;
}

/**
 * Writes file with name according to vector size (e.g. 100000.csv)
 * if needToWrite is true
 * @param vector
 * @param needToWrite
 */
void writeFileIfNeeded(vector<string> &vector, bool needToWrite) {
    if (needToWrite) {
        ofstream csvFile;
        string filename = to_string(vector.size()) + ".csv";

        csvFile.open(filename, fstream::out);
        for (const auto &i : vector) {
            csvFile << i << "\n";
        }
        csvFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @andreee Thank you for your answer. Yeah, Knuth says the truth :) I agree about calculating the hash sum, I didn't think about that. But what about the first loop int the convert function? It's not a reduce operation, is it? Actually, I didn't think about OpenMP. But I will try that either. Is OpenMP okay with Linux? Maybe if I delete unnecessary #pragmas it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is causing the segmentation fault is the way you compile your code and not the pragmas (which don't have any effect in gcc anyway, see below):

> gcc -w -funroll-loops -O2 -fno-inline -fipa-pta -msse2
>   -funsafe-math-optimizations -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=1 -fopt-info-optimized=logs/optOpt.txt -shared -fPIC singleThread.cpp

- By using `-shared -fPIC` you are creating a DSO (dynamic shared object). If you try to execute this file, you'll get an invalid PC (program counter) and your program will crash immediately. You must compile your code *without* `-shared -fPIC` (and use `-pie -fPIE` if you need a position-independent *executable*).
- Also, for compiling C++ code you should normally use `g++` instead of `gcc`.
- The given pragmas should not have any effect on your code, as these ones are only understood by Microsoft Visual Studio. Add `-Wall` to your compile options and gcc will show you the respective warnings.
- In any case, you should get rid of vendor-specific pragmas and use standardized solutions like OpenMP instead (compile with `-fopenmp`). That way, you are a step closer to writing compiler-independent code.
- As for the parallelized loops, you should make sure you don't run into race conditions or other synchronization failures. For example, to compute a sum, `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+: sum)` is your friend in OpenMP ([reference sheet](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-4.0-C.pdf)).

Disclaimer: I have used gcc 7.3.0 on x86_64 (CentOS Linux).

Comment: Thank you for you answer. This is very helpful. When I compile with -openmp option should I use another options from my example either? Or -openmp option is enough?

Comment: `-fopenmp` is enough.